# The mess in your room reflects on you. (Is this idiomatic?)

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-usage

> The mess in your room reflects on you.

Is this sentence idiomatic? (The intended meaning is "the mess=your status of mind or situation")

Comment: It's "okay", but I'm guessing most native speakers would include a negative / critical *adverb* in such contexts: *The mess in your room reflects **badly** on you, His polite reply reflected **well** on him*. The relevant definition from the full OED being 11b. (intransitive.) *To throw (indirect) light on a person or thing; to be revealing about; (also **with modifying adverb**) to reveal **in a particular light**; to create a (good, bad, etc.) impression.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I couldn't quite understand the meaning. Does "The mess in your room reflects badly on you" mean: 1-You are an disorganized person, so is your room. (no surprise) 2-Your room is untidy, so people will think you are a disorganized person, too (although you are not.)

Comment: @yunus: It means your interpretation #2 - excluding the "although you are not" caveat (that depends *entirely* on the people involved; the words themselves carry no such implication). By which I mean that to a first approximation, *This reflects badly on you* specifically and only means *in the perception of other people* (effectively, it implies little or nothing about what the speaker *himself* thinks).

Comment: Actually, I suppose that since the speaker *is* physically present, if he refers to *reflections / appearances / superficial impressions*. we can assume he's contrasting them with something ***more true*** that he sees (because he's *there*). But I certainly wouldn't want to say *This reflects well on him* implies that I ***don't*** endorse him.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's example is completely understandable but, as @FumbleFingers in the comments suggested, it really needs the adverb *badly*

1. The mess in your room reflects on you.
2. *The mess in your room reflects ***badly on*** you*. (idiomatic)

However, in this type of expression, the speaker is often expressing disappointment and is warning the listener that he or she is ***making a bad impression***.

Instead, if the speaker's intention is to say that the room is an *accurate* reflection of the listener's personality or lack of organisational skills then I'd suggest the following:

> 3. *The mess in your room is the **epitome** of your disorganisation*

From *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitome)*

> **An epitome** (/ɪˈpɪtəmiː/; Greek: ἐπιτομή, from ἐπιτέμνειν *epitemnein* meaning "to cut short") is a summary or miniature form, or an instance that **represents a larger reality**, also used as a synonym for embodiment.

Or

> 4. *The mess in your room **speaks volumes** about you. [i.e your untidiness]*

from *[Cambridge Dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/speak-volumes)*

> If something **speaks volumes**, it makes an opinion, characteristic, or situation very clear without the use of words. • *She said very little but her face spoke volumes.*